# What is the difference between pom.xml and testng.xml?

Tags: xml, eclipse, selenium, testng, pom.xml

I test a website using testng and selenium in Eclipse. 
My understanding:

- pom.xml function is to give overall structure of what plugins I want
  to run for the whole project, what dependencies and plugins it must
  wireup together to run my test cases smoothly.
- testng.xml is just a template to run one particular suite(collection
  of small test cases)I can include and structure different cases in my
  fashion.

**Can I have many testng.xml files?**
Can someone give better explanation of the difference between them?

Comment: testng.xml is used by TestNG to know which tests to run. pom.xml is used by Maven to know how to build the project. They have nothing in common, except they're both xml files. To learn about testng, read the documentation: http://testng.org/doc/index.html.

Comment: yes you can have multiply tests .xml files. Cause one xml contain one test suite. If you test big platform you need to implement a lot.. of test suites. For example now im writing test for aplication which has about ~25 .xml test suite configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

- **testng.xml** is the configuration for TestNG testing framework (e.g. defining test suites, test listeners, etc...)
- **pom.xml** is the configuration for Maven build tool (e.g. defining build plugins, compile and test dependencies, build profiles, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Maven is used for project management. It helps you in building your code/project effectively without much human intervention needed, once you have written your pom.xml correctly. It will download all the required artifacts, resolve the dependencies and then will compile your code and package it.

TestNG is a testing framework used to create, run and generate a report of your tests. TestNG can also be invoked using Maven. To run the tests too, sometimes you may depend on the dev code or some other artifacts. In order to correctly download all the right versions, you mavenize your tests and then give a run using Maven. Maven is there to make a techie life easy.